# Windows XP full row select in detail view

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

My question is clear and simple I want to have full row select in detail view for Windows XP. There are some articles about a tool named `TrayProdder` but the website seems to be down and I cannot find it anywhere else on the internet. What options do I have. If is very necessary for me have full row select. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find TrayProdder, many of the links to trayprodder are Addware, and scam, and virus like, Avoid!  Even if they had the binary , they would be the older version.

This looks like the legit code project, with the source, link-back to his page is down. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32373/Windows-Explorer-in-XP-Now-with-Checkboxes-and-Ful
 (would need to compile source)

There are other 3rd party File manager software that has options for Full Row Select

[Q-Dir](http://www.q-dir.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir)  (takes getting used to, My favorite and free)

[Directory Opus](http://gpsoft.com.au) (A popular favorite, trial)

[Explorer2](http://zabkat.com/x2lite.htm)  (this was nice, has a lite version side-by-side)

Possibly [Total commander](http://www.ghisler.com/whatsnew.htm) (very popular, also has versions for other platforms)

Comment: The download of TrayProdder on this page appears to be clean of viruses according to VirusTotal....http://www.gr8tricks.com/2012/03/how-to-enable-checkboxes-on-icons-in.html

Comment: ^ Checks out, and is also the 1.1  http://www.mediafire.com/?brhql4qtk47gis1

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party.  I whipped up something simple for my own personal needs.  Inspired by TrayProdder.

XPRowSelect is a small program runs in the background (with or without a tray icon) and allow for full row selection while in detail view.  Source and binaries below:

https://github.com/CBecker2K/XPRowSelect